# can't eject one USB drive at at time: can only eject GROUPS of drives (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, usb, eject

I can't eject one USB drive at at time; I can only eject GROUPS of drives. Using the eject USB drives icon in the system tray, the drives are grouped (in ways that I don't understand; maybe by USB root hub?), but only the group names (e.g., "Eject GoFlex Disk") are selectable; the drive letters are grayed out and not selectable.  So, if there are several drives listed under one heading, I can eject ALL the drives under that heading at once, but NOT each drive individually.  This is extremely annoying (and horrible UI design).  (Note: "Group names" do not necessarily always contain the same type--or even brand--of drive.  Some WD, some Seagate; some externally-powered, some "passport" types; some attached directly to the machine, some attached to the docking station: all of these combos can occur within a "group," so there's seemingly no rhyme or reason to their groupings.)

Does anybody else experience this on Win7?  ...or know how to get around it (so I can eject ONLY ONE drive at a time)?  I've searched extensively online & can't find any mention of such an issue, although others I know with Win7 have the same situation.  (Maybe no one but me cares...??  ...but that would be very surprising.)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Can we see a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, that's the correct behavior. The groups of drives are actually the drives themselves; the drive letters correspond to partitions on each drive.

I'm assuming you are seeing something like this:

[image: Windows eject context menu]

You may also try some third-party USB disk eject tool, like [USB Disk Ejector](http://quickandeasysoftware.net/software/usb-disk-ejector).

Comment: I thought the same at first, but the OP seems to mention that they have multiple physical drives (not partitions) under each of the group names - "(Note: "Group names" do not necessarily always contain the same type--or even brand--of drive. Some WD, some Seagate; some externally-powered, some "passport" types; some attached directly to the machine, some attached to the docking station: all of these combos can occur within a "group," so there's seemingly no rhyme or reason to their groupings.)"

Comment: Hmm… then we really need a screenshot.